# Bingo Probability

Tags: probability

I was attempting the programming challenge [Bingo Probability](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/bingo/), and the solutions all seem to involve generating a bingo card, then running through iterations to determine the probability. Is there a simpler method that involves probability theory?

Comment: This link might help you: http://www.durangobill.com/Bingo.html Math is nice, but engineers love to do nasty things to solve problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

The traditional bingo game usually has a winner at all rounds. The probability is related to the total quantity of cards registered in the round, versus the amount of cards some user has .

If you have 1 card, and there are 100 cards in the round, you have 1/100 probability of winniing .

You can make the round longer or shorter if you change the generation of bingo cards, but this wont change the probability of winning for the players .

For better precision you can also calculate the probability by the total number of balls in game .